# Adding origin url as ?ref in the destination url

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have many google ad landing pages. Irrespective of the page, on clicking a button the user would be redirected to the same form. Therefore, I would like to track which page the user has come from.

I was thinking that there could be a way to add a ?ref= to the URL, but am unable to think of a way to implement it (I am new to development). My website is largely static on a Node server.

So, let's say a user comes from www.xyz.com/abc and lands on the form, www.xyz.com/form, I would like the URL of the latter to be something like www.xyz.com/form?ref=www.xyz.com/abc.

I will then store this url in a hidden field in the form to identify where the user landed on this form from.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I actually searched online to try something before posting here. However, wasn't able to find much. If you could point me to something to start, would be happy to try it first and then post an update here.